# Einstein Web recommendation based on product categoris

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

I would like to create product recommendation based on categories.

My scenario is as follows:

1. When customer views category A, he should only see the recommendations in the email related to Category A promotions (ex. xx% discounted category A or category A related products).

I'm not sure if this can be done by 'Category view' scenario. If yes, how can we display promotional products in the email which are stored in a data extension.

Comment: You can't use Einstein Web Recommendations to present promotional products which are stored in a data extension, only those stored in Einstein catalogue, based on recommendation scenarios.

Comment: @LukasLunow Then do we have to upload all promotional data in Einstein product catalog and then filter it in rule manager? or should it be handled in Ampscript

Comment: You are correct. All products should be in the catalogue, and filtering should be done in the scenario.

Comment: Thanks @LukasLunow